# angular-ui-bootstrap cdn name on cdnjs.cloudflare.com site not matching with bower name

Tags: gruntjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, cdn, bower-install, google-cdn

When we do install `angular-ui-bootstrap` by command in bower like below
`bower install angular-bootstrap --save-dev`

Which will create folder named `angular-bootstrap` with data.

Due to this task inside grunt `grunt-google-cdn` will replace
`bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js` 
with cdn link when `cdnify` task is executed from grunt with the version present inside bower.

**Currently** string in the html in which we will have
`bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js`
which will replace with the link
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-bootstrap/1.1.2/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js 
***(which is not exists)***

**Expected** string should be
`bower_components/angular-ui-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js`

that will give us the link exactly present on the clodflare site as below
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/1.1.2/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js

**Either name should be changed on the cloudflare to match with every places**